# Nattable in SashForm expands the ScrolledComposite

Tags: swt, nattable, scrolledcomposite

I have a View(ScrolledForm) that contains two columns. In each column there is a SashForm and each section of the SashForm contains a Nattable. Now the requirement is that once the Sections widths (weights for the Sash) is done and the view is closed the same widths must be used (for good user experience).

[image]
The code works perfectly fine till the section is squeezed enough to make just the header of the nattable visible. Now after that when the composite is opened again, the section with the squeezed nattable expands and all the other sections expand proportionately (the weights are stored in the cache).

The observation is that when the section is squeezed to display two or less rows the view shows scrollbars (since the view is expanded).

Comment: You need to show us an [mcve]

Comment: An example, screenshot and possibly some example code would be helpful. And you should also ask a question and not only explain what happens. I don't understand what your problem is. But I can say that if you have not enough space to show the body region of a NatTable, you won't have scrollbars, because the scrollbars in a NatTable are bound to the body. Once you only show the header, you are not able to scroll anymore.

Comment: @Dirk I have one question.
If for the nattable I have the GridData specifying the heightHint, I should have the heightHint as no of rows visible * row height OR need to add the header (column) size as well which in my case is 40 pixels to the formula mentioned above. The Nattable scrollbar is not a concern for me. All the nattables must fit into the ScrolledForm without the user having to scroll the form (he can scroll the tables).

Comment: You need to add the header row height

Comment: @Dirk In the sashForm that contains three Nattable if the first Section is squeezed small enough to only show the header section of the Nattable i.e without any row visible and use the same weights to show the sections the first section expands to show 2 rows i.e (80 pixels which is same when the size is computed using Default).
The same behavior is not there when the sections are squeezed enough to show the headers of those table.

Comment: Sorry but without code and screens I don't understand your problem

Comment: I have added a screenshot of how the view looks.
@Dirk The only peace of code used for specifying the height from the cache is GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, true).applyTo(natTable); If the first section (Section Header 3 in our case) is squeezed enough to only show the header of the table the section after being relaunched expands to show 2 rows and since it takes the weights from the cache the scrolls are visible.

Comment: Still not sure what you mean. But with regards to scrollbars we fixed something a while ago. Which version of NatTable do you use?

Comment: Nattable version is 1.1.0